# Chrome.extensions : Open tab > Execute script > Close tab

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome-extension

Bonjour Gurus, i want to create a chrome extension like a web-scraper.

The "tab" button should : Open tab > execute script > close tab

but at the moment, the tabs is created but the "executescript" and "remove" are ignored, what i am missing???

i think this is a very simple feature, but i'm still very new into chrome.extensions.

Hope you will have a nice day.

Regards.
NCNN.

[app.js]

```js
var stock;

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request)
{
    stock = request;
    $.get('https://myweb.com/GetData.php?THEDATA=' + stock, function(data)
    {

    });
});

$('#tab').click(function()
{
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: 'https://stackoverflow.com/' },   function(tab)
    {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id,
            {
                code : "chrome.runtime.sendMessage(mycommand);"
            }, () => chrome.runtime.lastError);

        chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);
    });
});
```

[popup.html]

```html
<h1>MYtest</h1>
<button id="tab">Open Tab</button>


<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

[manifest.json]

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "TestJB",
    "description": "TESTDESC",
    "version": "1.0",
    "permissions":
    [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*",
        "tabs",
        "activeTab",
        "alarms",
        "clipboardRead",
        "clipboardWrite",
        "bookmarks",
        "contextMenus",
        "contentSettings",
        "downloads",
        "history",
        "nativeMessaging",
        "browsingData",
        "proxy",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "cookies",
        "webNavigation",
        "storage",
        "tabCapture",
        "notifications",
        "<all_urls>",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "debugger"
    ],
    "browser_action":
    {
        "default_icon": "img/icon_128.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "icons": 
    {
        "128" : "img/icon_128.png"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this worked for me.

[app.js]

```js
var stock;

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request)
{
    stock = request;
    $.get('https://myweb.com/GetData.php?THEDATA=' + stock, function(data)
    {

    });
});

$('#tab').click(function()
{
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: 'https://stackoverflow.com/', active: false },    function(tab)
    {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id,
            {
                code : "chrome.runtime.sendMessage(mycommand);"
            }, () => chrome.runtime.lastError);

        chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);
    });
});
```